# How to update a document using the Elasticsearch Update API?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed a document in Elasticsearch as follows:

```
{
 _parent: chow-demo
 _index: prototype_2013.01.02
 _type: chow-clfg
 _id: Nx4JcvyxTPujkyy0Jq5BNw
 _score: 11.600378
 _source: {
  chow-clfg: {
  @type: chow-clfg
  clfg: Cg5iV00z4woYAAAARQ0
  @timestamp: 2013-01-02T06:26:00.000Z
  count: 1
  }
 }
}
```

I tried to update the count field by the following command:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/prototype_2013.01.02/chow-clfg/Nx4JcvyxTPujkyy0Jq5BNw/_update' -d '{"script":"ctx._source.chow-clfg.count+=num","params":{"num":1}}'
```

However I received the following error instead:

```
{"error":"RemoteTransportException[[Vesta][inet[/10.15.78.249:9300]][update]]; nested: DocumentMissingException[[prototype_2013.01.02][0] [chow-clfg][Nx4JcvyxTPujkyy0Jq5BNw]: document missing]; ","status":404}
```

What exactly have I done that is missing? I was following the documents at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/update.html and yet it doesn't work.

Also, I included the parent field:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/prototype_2013.01.02/chow-clfg/Nx4JcvyxTPujkyy0Jq5BNw/_update' -d '{"parent":"chow-demo","script":"ctx._source.chow-clfg.count+=num","params":{"num":1}}'
```

And it still didn't work. Anyone can help me with this error?

Comment: Are you sure that the document you are trying to update exists?

Comment: Definitely; it had to exist. Somehow the documentation doesn't really show the syntax of how it should be indexed clearly. Or I could have misread the documentation.

Comment: Try : `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/prototype_2013.01.02/chow-clfg/Nx4JcvyxTPujkyy0Jq5BNw'`, what is the output? . Also, you using `ES 0.19+`, right ?

Comment: I am using a _ttl so my documents don't live beyond 30 minutes. I queried one of the existing ids and it gave: {"_index":"prototype_2013.01.03","_type":"chow-clfg","_id":"XQZc6tooQwG8GZhz9e-MaQ","exists":false} However when I do a search query, I am able to find the document. Any reason why this is so?

Comment: Are you using `routing` while indexing? If yes, you'll need to provide this routing value while using `-XGET`.

Answer (score 3):

Basically it was incorrect syntax that caused the problem of not being able to update.

Error:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/prototype_2013.01.02/chow-clfg/Nx4JcvyxTPujkyy0Jq5BNw/_update'  \
    -d '{"script":"ctx._source.chow-clfg.count+=num","params":{"num":1}}'
```

Correct syntax:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/prototype_2013.01.02/chow-clfg/Nx4JcvyxTPujkyy0Jq5BNw/_update?parent=chow-demo'
    -d '{"script":"ctx._source[\"chow-demo\"].count+=num","params":{"num":1}}'
```

The parent mapping should be included, together with the type name in its proper syntax:

```
ctx._source[\"chow-demo\"].count+=num
```

Comment: How can I implement this using php ?